# В чем отличие git fetch --all и git remote update?

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Есть ли отличие между командами `git fetch --all` и `git remote update`, и если есть, то в чем она заключается?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вроде бы эти команды эквивалентны. Есть некоторые различия в поведении.

Согласно документации, `git remote update` смотрит на переменную конфигурации `remotes.default`. Если эта переменная определена, то будут обновлены только указанные remote'ы. Иначе (если не определена), то будут обновлены все кроме тех, для которых переменная `remote.<name>.skipDefaultUpdate` установлена в `true`.

Опять же, согласно документации, `git fetch --all` обновляет просто все remote'ы, без исключений.

Таким образом, если вы не добавляли необычных настроек, то команды эквивалентны.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того, в варианте `git remote update` есть полезный ключик `-P` (сокращение от *prune*). Если указать его, то команда сотрёт из локального репозитория ветки, которые уже не существуют удалённо.